# Difference when obtaining value of the clicked html element across browsers

Tags: jquery, html

```js
$(function ()
{
  $('button').on("click", show);
});

function show(e)
{
  $("#data").append(e.target.nodeName+', ');
  $("#data").append(e.target.value+'<br>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn" value="test">
<span>click here</span>
</button>

<div id="data">

</div>
```

Test the above code in Chrome and Firefox. Both gives different results.

When attaching `click` event to a button using jquery and obtain the value of the clicked element, firefox and chrome gives different results. Note that the button element contain a span inside it.

I am detecting the element and getting the value using event.target.nodeName and event.target.value.

Please see this [jsfiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/dy1ubgkc/4/) in firefox and chrome. Both gives different results.

What is the best cross browser solution for this. please help

EDIT: it is interesting to note that chromes behavior to this code is random. After each refresh, the output in chrome may change.

Comment: after all that's what jquery was made for ;) cross browser compatibility

Comment: so, u are suggesting to get the value using $(e.target).text()?

Comment: no i suggest taking a look at Zenoo's solution down there. you don't need to mess with `e` in both vanilla js and jquery you can use `this` or `${this}` to refer to the target. in addition jquery will normalize attributes so they are cross browser compatible.

Comment: @GottZ, thanks, i do not have much experience in coding and did not know using e for getting values will cause issues. I will use 'this' as suggested.

Comment: `e` is the event. `this` is the element on wich the event triggered. using `e` is perfectly fine but you should use `this` when you want to mess with the element that has the event assigned. `e.target` can vary from `this` in case you have a click handler on `<body>` for example, it would provide you with the element you actually clicked. not `<body>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use JQuery `$(this)` selector, you won't have to worry about Firefox/Chrome .

Also, if you want the attribute `value` of your element, `.val()` is here for you, but if you want the text instead, use `.text()`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').on("click", function() {
    $("#data").append('<p>'+this.nodeName + '</p><p>'+$(this).text() + '</p>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn" value="test">
<span>click here</span>
</button>

<div id="data">

</div>
```